# How to create a value type or string type object at runtime using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, object, instantiation

Probably simple but could not figure out. I am loading an assembly at runtime and browsing through some classes and generating input controls for its properties. To create an instance of an object at runtime I am using:

```
  object o =  PropertyType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public, null, Type.EmptyTypes,null).Invoke(null);
```

and it works fine for class types. When the type is an array, I use

```
  object o =  PropertyType.Type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int) }).Invoke(new object[] { 0 });
```

which also works fine. But when it comes to string type or value types GetConstructor.Invoke does not work. I also tried Activator.CreateInstance which also did not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're running into is that value types don't really have parameterless constructors. C# makes it *look* like they do, but they don't at the CLR level.

`Activator.CreateInstance` should work fine for real value types though:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(int));
Console.WriteLine(o); // Prints 0
```

This will always give the default value for any value type.

Now, you're asking about strings - what string would you expect to create? The default value for the `string` type is null - but would you want the empty string instead? If so, you'll need to special-case that code.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I edited my question, Did not mean to say string is a value type... So how about string instantiation?

Comment: @Erkan: I've edited my answer. What string do you want to create? If you pick a constructor that actually exists, you can certainly invoke it with reflection - but of course you'll need to supply the values for the parameters...

Comment: just want to instantiate a class property dynamically which is of type string, but I do not want the null value in the created object. So I guess I need to do special-case for string type properties in the class. Still not clear on how to create the object instance from a string type class property though. Since I will do a special-case would : if (property.PropertyType==typeof(string) ) object o = "" ; be sufficient?

Comment: @Erkan: Yes, that would do it. But is the default value for all other value types *really* useful? Can you give a bit more information about what you're going to do with the value? Maybe there's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to instantiate arbitrary objects with particular values, one thing you can check is if there is a TypeConverter that supports converting an instance (with the value you want to match) to an [InstanceDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor.aspx).  I'm not entirely sure what you're doing (your example suggests you're trying to create 'default' instances of the different objects), but just thought I'd mention this in case it's relevant.  I use this in Emit code to emit arbitrary constant values to the stack via IL.  Here's the snippet that gets the InstanceDescriptor:

```
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value);
        if (converter.CanConvertTo(typeof (InstanceDescriptor)))
        {
            var desc = (InstanceDescriptor) converter.ConvertTo(value, typeof (InstanceDescriptor));
        }
```

The descriptor specifies a means of constructing the instance, which could be calling a constructor, calling a static method, accessing a static property or accessing a static field.  It also specifies whether the construction completely sets the value of the type to match your original instance; if not, you'll need to do additional reflection and setting of properties.

This is the mechanism that the WinForms Designer uses when generating the code-behind for the controls on the form, so it is supported for the common types that show up as properties of controls accessible from the designer.

Answer (score 0):

The `int` type [doesn't have any constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32_members.aspx).

The code you write is going to depend on the property's type; normally, you'd write special-case code for `string`, `int` and other primitive types.

Your code above contains the literal 0; how do you decide what values to pass to the constructors?